# How to declare a parameter that implements several protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom UIView which contains an UIPickerView. What I want to do now is to create a function to pass a parameter as the delegate of the UIPickerView:

```
class MQPickerView: UIView {

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

     ......

    func setDelegate(delegate: AnyObject) {

        self.pickerView.dataSource = delegate
        self.pickerView.delegate = delegate

    }

}
```

I try the type AnyObject at first, but it can not be passed to dataSource and delegate of pickerView. How can I declare the paramter type to express that I need a parameter which implements the dataSource and delegate of pickerView?

Comment: I think, you have to pass your delegate as reference. Try using "inout" parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic parameter with `where` clause like this:

**Swift 3:**

```
func setDelegate<T>(delegate: T) where T: UIPickerViewDelegate, T:UIPickerViewDataSource {
    self.pickerView.dataSource = delegate
    self.pickerView.delegate = delegate
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
 func setDelegate<T where T: UIPickerViewDelegate, T:UIPickerViewDataSource>(delegate: T)  {}
```

Comment: the compiler error: "Consecutive declaration on a line must be seperated by ;"

Comment: are you using swift 2 or swift 3?

Comment: @itenyh Updated the answer. Should work for you now.